# Is it safe to bite into caffeine tablets?

Tags: caffeine, pill, medication-directions

I'm taking these tablets called Pro Plus. When I swallow a tablet, I don't really feel much, but if I chew it up before swallowing it in very small pieces I feel a much bigger impact. Perhaps the benefits are shorter lived but I haven't really noticed that. Is it safe to do this? The packaging makes it clear that you're supposed to swallow whole but I just don't get the same effect.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It very much depends on the type of the tablet: coated or not; if coated with what type of film; is it an immediate or sustained release tablet etc. The manufacturer has these information and has probably had them in mind when they made the recommendations on how to use the medicine,